# File is taking up a lot of space on server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, linux-server

I have this file on my Ubuntu server, and it is 12GB in file size. I don't know what that file is, and would like to know, would be safe to to delete or truncate the file?

Here is the file

```
/var/log/cbpolicyd.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that's a mail logfile for Zimbra/postfix (mail server).

It depends on the IT policy for the server.  If it's not a business server, then do whatever you want if you don't need to troubleshoot any mail logs.  If it's a business server, depending on the type of business, you may need to archive and keep the data for 7 to 10 years, unless your IT policy states you only keep logs for X amount of time.

Otherwise, you have free reign over it.

Comment: Just as a reminder "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks" are off-topic so you don't need to cover them in your answers